# Vertical alignment is off on date type input

Tags: css, html, types, datepicker, mobile-safari

everyone

I am using an HTML5 date type input in a web form.

Here are the html blocks:

```
<div><!--birthdate-->
    <label for="birthdate" class="col1">Birthdate: </label> 
    <input type="date" class="col2" name="birthdate" id="birthdate" required>
</div><!--END birthdate-->
```

And the css rules for them:

```
.col1{text-align:right; width:111px; display:inline-block;}

.col2{width:162px; display:inline-block;}
```

Breakdown of browser behaviors:

Desktop Safari and Desktop Chrome are both working as expected.

iOS Safari from an iPad: the input field is slightly above its label.

Desktop Firefox displays it as a text-type input field.

I don't have enough rep to post an image, but can send individual answerers one on request.

Does anyone know a decent solution or workaround for this?

Comment: any way you can compile a fiddle?

Comment: You can use CSS to tweak your date field:  
       input[type=date] {
   width: 150px;
       }

For the iPad you would have to write a media query to make its own adjustment.

Comment: I don't think this would affect the iPad display the way that I want.  I already have a width rule tied to the col2 class.  My problem is vertical alignment, not horizontal.

Comment: @Newbian I am having the same issue with input type date. Vertical alignment is ignored only on mobile safari, whereas input type text works as expected. All other browsers work as expected. Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Safari iOS 8.3 and Bootstrap 3, it worked for me with this:

```html
<input type="date" style="vertical-align:bottom;">
```

Comment: This does not work on iPad with the latest iOS. using the style has no effect what so ever. The text of the date is still shifted up.

Answer (score 2):

-To answer your question about Firefox:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/986096

The input *date* **isn't** currently supported, so you'd have to look for an alternative if you really want to make it compatible with the browser.

-As far as the change in alignment, you can try something like this in the CSS:

```
input[type=date] { 
     padding-top: 2px; /* margin-top: 2px; ... */
}
```

Change the *2px* to whatever works best.

-So that changes in the alignment are only visible when viewed on an iPad, as suggested above in the comments, you will need to use a **media query**, like such:

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) {
  /* put input[type=date] {...} here */
}
```

For more: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/ipad-specific-css/

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to have no effect on the iPad browser.  Even tweaking the padding without the media query only shows positive results on desktop browsers.

Comment: If that doesn't work, try others, here's a full list of media querry's, give each a try (keep in mind that you may also modify the padding or margin based on the orientation of the iPad...): http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/